# how to count user_id based notifications?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

all members see the same counts in the software.  How can I make it count specifically for user_id?

```html
 @php $check_count = \App\Models\Support::where('status', 2)->get()
 @endphp
 
<li class="header__menu-item"> <span>Support</span>
 @if(count($check_count) == 0)  @else   <span class="notification
 notranslate">{{count($check_count)}}</span> @endif </li>
```

[mysql picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsOaL.png)

I wanted to count notifications based on user_id, but I couldn't manage to count them based on member.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    @php
$user_id = auth()->user()->id; // Assuming you are using Laravel authentication and the user is logged in
$check_count = \App\Models\Support::where('user_id', $user_id)
                                  ->where('status', 2)
                                  ->get();
@endphp

<li class="header__menu-item">
    <span>Support</span>
    @if(count($check_count) == 0)
    @else
        <span class="notification notranslate">{{ count($check_count) }}</span>
    @endif
</li>
```

Comment: ParseError
syntax error, unexpected variable "$user_id" (View: /home/toporasa/public_html/resources/views/theme/deepblue/frontend/layouts/partials/nav.blade.php) 


i got this error


$cart_total = App\Models\Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->sum('quantity');
above code works for cart. Do I need to do it this way too? I tried a few things but I couldn't do it.

Comment: $user_id = auth()->id(); 
$check_count = \App\Models\Support::where('status', 2)
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->get();

like that its work thank you so much

Comment: Yes auth()->id() is in Laravel 10

Answer (score 0):

```
 @php $check_count = \App\Models\Support::all()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) @endphp
```